# Error with Microsoft Visual C++ for Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, visual-c++, pip

I am trying to install the library Fatiando in Python with 
`pip install fatiando`
but I keep getting the message
`error: command 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\link.exe' failed with exit status 1`

I tried to reinstall Visual C++ for Python v9.0 but it didn't work.
Can someone please help me?

My Python version is 2.7.

Comment: Pass `-v` to *pip*. That will produce more output and maybe you'll see the error.

Comment: What do you mean with pass -v?

Comment: `pip -v install fatiando`.

Comment: "Failed building wheel for fatiando"